# PostgreSQL return word after matching first character

Tags: postgresql, regex

I would like to return the words beginning with ':' from `'select :barns, :fowl, :cows from farm'` using regexp_matches.

So far I have:

```
select regexp_matches('select :barns, :fowl, :cows from farm', '([:])\w+', 'g')
```

But this only returns the set `{:}, {:}, {:}`. I would like it to return `{:barns}, {:fowl}, {:cows}`

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That was an issue with the regex syntax. To get the desired word, you will have to group it under ()

```
            SELECT
                regexp_matches(
                    'select :barns, :fowl, :cows from farm',
                    '(:\w+)',
                    'g'
                )
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps this will fit your needs?

```
SELECT regexp_matches('select :barns, :fowl, :cows from farm', '(:[a-zA-Z]*)', 'g');
```

Cheers!